# The $ when used in a key name in yml disappears

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-el

I am using application.yml within a springboot application and loading a map.  Unfortunately, whenever I have a $ character in the key, it simply disappears.  The key/value pair is there, just without any $ signs.  I've tried various ways of attempting to escape the character but nothing seems to work.  I can't see any documentation that states that $ is a special character - except perhaps within classpath notation?  Is this what is happening here?  And if it is, how do I escape it?

```
first:
  second:
    third:
      'aaa': "aaa"
      '$bbb': "bbb"
      '$ccc': "ccc"
      $$yy$y: "yyyy"
```

In this example, the map is defined as

```
private Map<String, String> third;
```

Comment: There's a comma at the end of the line with "yyyy" that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks, That'll be a typo entering in the question.  I also tried to use third: {a:a, b:b} notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```yaml
first:
  second:
    third:
      "[aaa]": "aaa"
      "[$bbb]": "bbb"
      "[$ccc]": "ccc"
      "[$$yy$y]": "yyyy"
```

```
{aaa=aaa, $bbb=bbb, $ccc=ccc, $$yy$y=yyyy}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class So71584675Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71584675Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Props props) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(props.third);
        };
    }

}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.second")
class Props {

    Map<String, String> third;

    Props(Map<String, String> third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

    Map<String, String> getThird() {
        return this.third;
    }

    void setThird(Map<String, String> third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how would you write literal brackets `[]`?

Comment: That, I don't know; I based my answer on something I saw in the Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Comment: Yes, thankyou! That works!  Strange though...

Comment: You saved me. I found the content for it in the Spring Boot Docs "Binding Maps"

`When binding to Map properties you may need to use a special bracket notation so that the original key value is preserved. If the key is not surrounded by [], any characters that are not alpha-numeric, - or . are removed.`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.14/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps